# How to select multiple rows from another table inside a subquery in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a query structured as following.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      name,
      last_updated,
      user_id,
      (SELECT id, name FROM user WHERE user_id = m.user_id) AS care_coordinator_list
    FROM 
      cohort AS a 
      LEFT JOIN map_cohort_user AS m ON m.cohort_id = a.cohort_id
    WHERE 
      a.creator_id = UUID_TO_BIN_F(:id);
```

There is a simple join between two tables called cohort and map_cohort_user with some conditions in the where clause. Now for each row returned in this query, I also want to return a field called 'care_coordinator_list' which will be selected from a completely different table called 'user' and will contain multiple rows. Doing it this way gets me an error saying "Multiple rows returned from the subquery". The subquery only works if only individual data is returned, which I guess is the expected way.

What should be the proper way to implement it like such.
I'm using rds with aws lambda in javascript, for reference.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

it depends what the expected result.

but for this case, I suggest just to use join instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  name,
  last_updated,
  user_id,
  user.id,
  user.name
FROM 
  cohort AS a 
  LEFT JOIN map_cohort_user AS m ON m.cohort_id = a.cohort_id
  LEFT JOIN user ON m.cohort_id = a.cohort_id
WHERE 
  a.creator_id = UUID_TO_BIN_F(:id);
```